# A strongly convergent bounded linear operator in a Banach spaces implies the existence of a dense subset?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $A_i:X\to Y$, for $i\in \mathbb{N}$, be a sequence of bounded linear operator, and suppose $\sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} ||A_i|| < \infty$.

How can it then be shown that if there exists a bounded linear operator $A:X\to Y$ such that $A_i$ converges strongly to $A$, and $||A|| \le \lim \inf_{i\to\infty}||A_i||$, then we can find a dense subset $D \subset X$ such that $(A_i x)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ for every $D$?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if $A_n\to A$ strongly, this means that $A_nx\to Ax$ for all $x\in X$. So $\{A_nx\}$ is Cauchy for all $x\in X$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami but how do we find the dense subset $D$?

Comment: With  the problem as stated, take  $D=X $.